# error codes and out of margins on equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

im getting 8 error codes on this equation, and also it goes way out of my margins, so you cant see all of it?

Can anyone spot the mistakes?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

%Margins 
\usepackage[margin=3.cm,left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=3cm,headsep=1cm,includefoot,]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\centering
UHT_{strækning, 1år} = (0.005798*2898^{0.49}*0.46km)+(0.005798*2695^{0.49}*1.1km)+(0.005798*1410^{0.49}*0.7km) = 0.13 + 0.31 + 0.14 = 0.58
 \: uheld\;pr.\; km\; pr.\; år.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A few things, æøå is not allowed in math mode so use `_{\textrm{strækning, 1år}}`. Also have a look as the `siunitx` package for proper formatting of units.

Comment: @daleif 
both didnt help on the error codes, but thanks for the heads up with the package.
Edit: the code for æ å ø removed the errors, thanks! now i just have trouble with the formatting!

Comment: Added my margin package.

Comment: The error is `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` because there is no `\begin{document}`  but perhaps you meant to ask about a different error, you have not said what error you got.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. You MWE cannot be compiled as is

Comment: if you add begin{document} the error is `! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.`  which would be resolved with the change in the first comment from daleif.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I'd do with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
% make æøå proper letters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% more math
\usepackage{amsmath}
%Margins 
\usepackage[margin=3.cm,left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,top=3cm,headsep=1cm,includefoot,]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% format numbers and units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{UHT}_{\textrm{strækning, 1år}} = {}& (0.005798\cdot 2898^{0.49}\cdot
\SI{0.46}{\km})+(0.005798\cdot 2695^{0.49}\cdot \SI{1.1}{\km})
\\
&+(0.005798\cdot
1410^{0.49}\cdot \SI{0.7}{\km})
\\
= {} & 0.13 + 0.31 + 0.14 =
\SI{0.58}{uheld\per\km\per \textrm{år}}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```